# How to update camera up vector when I rotate it?

Tags: vector, three.js, camera, rotation, geometry

I am willing to make an FPS "fly-mode" THREE.js application (camera yaw and pitch angles are modified whenever the mouse is moved). I also want to have it have WASD controls, with A and D being used to strafe left and right respectively. This is my code so far:

```
onkeydown(event) {
        var distance = 1.1;
        var v;

        const vecFront = this.camera.getWorldDirection();

        switch (event.key) {
            case "w":
                v = vecFront.multiplyScalar(distance);
                break;

            case "s":
                v = vecFront.multiplyScalar(-distance);
                break;

            case "a":
                // don't know
                break;

            case "d":
                // don't know
                break;
        }

        this.camera.position.add(v);
    }
```

For going forward and backward, the code works fine. For the left and right vectors I think camera.up comes into play, but I don't know how. If you provide code, please explain everything in detail (geometrically). Thank you in advance for your help.

**P.S.:** I know there are already some THREE.js files that do this, but the point is for me to learn some basic geometry.

Comment: FYI `camera.up` is not something one typically changes in three.js. It is used, for example, by `camera.lookAt( point )` to keep the camera level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right vector `R` is given by the *vector cross-product* of the world direction (`W`) and the up vector (`U`):

`R = (W.y * U.z - W.z * U.y, W.z * U.x - W.x * U.z, W.x * U.y - W.y * U.x)`

Remember to normalize this vector before you use it.

---

However, there is a more efficient way, using the *view matrix* of the camera (given by the `matrixWorldInverse` field). The (*already normalized too!*) right vector is given by the first three elements of the *first* row of the matrix.

Comment: I did what you proposed in the first place  (`v = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(vecUp, vecFront).normalize().multiplyScalar(-distance);`), but it only worked in the initial position with `camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)`. I think it has something to do with the fact that I constantly rotate the camera (with mouse movements), but camera.up does not update automatically? But now that you mentioned the view matrix and how I can get camera.up, maybe I can fix that. Also, what if W and U are perpendicular? Isn't W x U = (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: It is zero if W and U are *parallel* (or anti-parallel), not perpendicular. I think the view matrix method is probably the best, since it is already normalized, and you don't even need any math processing.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I will try your method and come back with results.

Comment: Everything works well in the initial position only (yaw, pitch, going left, going right). But when I move the camera to a completely different position, all hell breaks lose and nothing seems to be working anymore (_e.g._ left goes right, yaw turns to roll). I guess I need to study this further and perhaps use left and right to move on an orbit rather than strafe left. My goal is to make controls like Minecraft creative mode when you fly if you know how that is.

Comment: Basically a free-flying camera? I'm wouldn't know why it doesn't work without looking at your code as a whole.

Comment: Yes, a free flying camera. You can find the JS code here (if I'm using this correctly):
https://jsfiddle.net/xurqtoau/1/

Comment: @VladAdrianMoglan oops I realised I made a mistake in the second part of the answer! I meant to write that you can actually directly obtain the *right* vector from the matrix with no effort, but I somehow wrote about the up vector again instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162635/discussion-between-vlad-adrian-moglan-and-meowgoesthedog).